# How to get a diagonal matrix from A vector

Tags: matlab

I have a column:

```
0.0677
0.0584
0.0487
0.0453
0.0394
```

What instruction would get the following output

```
0.0677   0          0         0          0
0        0.0584     0         0          0
0        0          0.0487    0          0
0        0          0         0.0453     0
0        0          0         0          0.0394
```

Comment: Can you check your MATLAB installation as I think there must be a problem with the help files installed? I just typed 'diagonal vector' into the MATLAB help dialog and the very first example on the very first page is this example with using diag().

Comment: @cMinor Thanks for asking this here, this question was useful to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I remember correctly there's a command called something like `diag(A)`

**Edit:** here you go, some documentation on the `diag`
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diag.html

pay particular attention to the quote:

> X = diag(v) puts v on the main diagonal, same as above with k = 0.

Answer (score 25):

diag is the normal MATLAB solution (as pointed out by posdef.) Thus

```
D = diag(vec);
```

gives you a matrix with diagonal elements as needed.

Perhaps better in some applications is to create a sparse matrix, since a diagonal matrix is quite sparse. So if you are doing matrix multiplies this will greatly help in reducing the number of unnecessary operations.

```
n = length(vec);
D = spdiags(vec(:),0,n,n);
```

If you truly wanted to do the assignment in an explicit form, use a single linear index like this:

```
n = length(vec);
D = zeros(n);
D(cumsum([1,repmat(n+1,1,n-1)])) = vec;
```

Or you could use the sub2ind function to convert a set of indices into a single index.

Comment: @woodchips: I think `diag` will return a special kind of matrix. You can check how many bytes is actually used by `whos("D")`. Thanks

Comment: @eat: No, `diag` returns an array of the same class as the original vector. So if the vector was a `double`, the resulting array is of class `double` as well.

Comment: @woodchips: To create the linear index, it may be simpler to write `1:(n+1):n^2` - no need for `cumsum` and `repmat`

Comment: @Jonas: Very odd, that's what I recall from Matlabs behavior for few years ago. Anyway current Octave (3.2.4) behaves as I explained, i.e. if d= rand(1e6, 1) and D= diag(d), then both d and D consumes (almost) the same amount of memory (almost meaning a truly insignificant difference). Clearly my point is that all the (trivial) structures ought to be recognized. Ahah, one thing: what do you mean by _'class'_, surely the data type  for d and D belongs to same _`class`_. Please can you show me the output for `whos("d")`and `whos("D"), where `d= rand(7, 1)`and D= diag(d)`. Thanks

Comment: @eat: with `d = [1 2 3 4];`, and `dd=diag(d)`, `d` takes 32bytes and `dd` takes 128 bytes on R2011a.

Comment: @Jonas: Thanks. So it seems then that only Octave is recognizing special matrices. With Octave 3.2.4 bot `d` and `D` takes 32 bytes.

Comment: Diag returns a full matrix (in matlab), although if the vector argument was itself sparse, then diag returns a sparse matrix.

Comment: why the `vec(:)` in `D = spdiags(vec(:),0,n,n);`?

Answer (score 3):

The following gives the diagonal matrix `D` whose diagonal is the vector `vec`. It is written in a vectorized fashion in MATLAB.

```
D      = zeros(numel(vec));
[I,J]  = ind2sub(size(D),1:numel(D));
ind    = [I(:) J(:)];
ind    = find(ind(:,1)==ind(:,2));
D(ind) = vec;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously you can do it in a C-like way. Right now I can't figure out more elegant solution.

```
vector;%Your vector
vec_length = length(vector);
A = zeros(vec_length);
for i=1:vec_length
   A(i,i)  = vector(i);
end;
```

Comment: The one thing I would not do is to use a loop. This is not the way to think in MATLAB. Instead, learn to think in terms of matrices and vectors in single operations.